# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS - When trying to access a method after storyBoard Initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, xctest, xctestcase

I am trying to write UT's for my viewController and I am initialising my viewController in the below way :

```
var sut: viewController!

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyBoardName", bundle: nil)
    sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard_identifier") as? viewController
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded() // Loads the view hierarchy
  }
```

The story board is initialised properly non-nil with the textLabels and default connections, but when I try to access any method present inside the viewControllerClass I get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

```
func testVC() {
  XCTAssertNotNil(sut) // this passes and I can see default values for attributes being assigned
  viewController.configure() // this gives EXEC_BAD_ACCESS although this is a non-private method
}
```

Comment: What is `viewController` in this scenario? I didn't see it, just a sut?

Comment: viewController is the viewController class that I am trying to instantiate, and sut was just the variable name which I was trying to use.

Comment: You are confusing things by not naming your class correctly. By convention, `ViewController` is a class name and `viewController` is an instance.  The code `viewController.configure()` looks like a call to a static function on your `viewController` class.  Is that right?  Don't you want `sut.configure()`?